# How does C++ Opengl circle function work

Tags: c++, opengl

I am reading a book of `opengl` and there is a function to draw a circle but I don't know how to put this function in my code and run it and also I don't know what parameter I put in this.

I am new to `opengl` and I am trying to figure it out.

**Code**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cmath>

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void display(void);
void drawCircle(float cx, float cy, float r, int num_segments);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutKeyboardFunc(&keyboard);
    glutDisplayFunc(&display);
    glutMainLoop();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
    case '\x1B':
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        break;
    }
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //drawCircle(, , , );
    glFlush();
}

void drawCircle(float cx, float cy, float r, int num_segments)
{
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_segments; i++)
    {
        float theta = i * (2.0f * PI / num_segments); // get the current angle
        float x = r * cos(theta); // calculate the x component
        float y = r * sin(theta); // calculate the y component
        glVertex2f(x + cx, y + cy); // output vertex
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

Comment: cx = center of the circle pos x, cy = center of circle pos y, r = radius of the circle, num_segments = number of points. More num_segments is important, more the circle is clear. You can try drawCircle(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 10); for example.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant i have underline in `PI` why its happening

Comment: #include <math.h> and use M_PI instead of PI.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant Error come identifier `M_PI` is undefined

Comment: Replace cmath with math.h  . If it doesn't work, replace M_PI with 3.14 to try

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant thanks for answer but if i want to make a half arc than what should i do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102066/discussion-between-hamel123-and-pierre-emmanuel-lallemant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing window creation and a setting the color of the circle you are
drawing:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#define M_PI 3.14159265359


void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void display(void);
void drawCircle(float cx, float cy, float r, int num_segments);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int width = 1280;
  int height = 720;
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_SINGLE);
  glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
  glutCreateWindow("circle");
  glutKeyboardFunc(&keyboard);
  glutDisplayFunc(&display);
  glutMainLoop();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
  switch (key)
  {
  case '\x1B':
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    break;
  }
}

void display()
{
  glColor3f(1.0, 0, 0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  gluOrtho2D(0.0, 1280, 0.0, 720);
  glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  drawCircle(640, 360, 100, 200);
  glFlush();
}

void drawCircle(float cx, float cy, float r, int num_segments)
{
  glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
  for (int i = 0; i < num_segments; i++)
  {
    float theta = i * (2.0f * M_PI / num_segments); // get the current angle
    float x = r * cos(theta); // calculate the x component
    float y = r * sin(theta); // calculate the y component
    glVertex2f(x + cx, y + cy); // output vertex
  }
  glEnd();
}
```

Comment: It's the for loop in drawCircle that draws the full circle.. If you change the range of the loop from 0..num_segments to a smaller range, you get an arc.

Comment: but i try to changing loop it's not happening like i =180